# How to keep session in android?

Tags: android, web-services, android-service, android-ksoap2

My app android have connect to webservice (.asmx) use ksoap2. But it has session. When i login service will keep session to manage user - client. But when i login success, session in webservice is keeping null? Can some body tell me why?

Answer (score 2):

Android is not able to define sessions, as it is a feature of web browsers. The simplest solution we had come up with was to send the sessionID of the web session along with the URL, for e.g.: `http://your.required.url/your.context/your.action;jsessionid=<the_current_session_id>?GET=PARAMETERS`