# Maintain the session after the Android app connect to web service

Tags: android

I'm using ksoap2 for web service method calls. First, the user must login. I want others method in web service could only be call after login. But i can not do that. Because I don't have any session in web service. I don't know how to do that in web service. How the web service know that user have already login in the android apps? Do you have any ideas, session or cookies :(. Thanks for reading my question. Here is my code in web service

```
public class Login {
String message;
Connection conn;
String url;
ResultSet rs;
Statement stmt;
public String login(String username, String password) {
    try {
        Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
        url = "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/FirstDB";
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(
                url, "postgres",
                "root");
        stmt = conn.createStatement();
        rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * From account Where username = '"+ username + "'and password = '" + password +"'");
        if ( rs.next() ) {
            message = "true";
        } else {
            message = "false";
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println("Got an exception! ");
        System.err.println(e.getMessage());
    }
    return message;
}

public String Test() {
    if(message.equals("true")) 
    {
        return "abc";
    }
    return "bdf";
}
```

}

In the android app. First I call the method login(), then method Test(). The result always be "bdf".

Answer (score 1):

To maintain sessions in the Android Application you can use shared preferences.

For example see [Android User Session Management using Shared Preferences](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/08/android-session-management-using-shared-preferences/)

or you can try in this way [Maintaining session in android ( application stay authenticated on the server side)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6054828/1265724)

Comment: Thank you but I want to keep the session in the web service, not the Shared Preferences in the android apps :(. Do you have any other ideas?

Comment: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11520099/how-to-keep-session-in-android) The question in this topic is similar to my problem. But the answer is no clear. And I don't know how to create a session in web service after the android apps have connected.

Comment: I think [this](http://metatroid.com/article/Android:%20handling%20web%20service%20authentication) link may help you.

Comment: This link is just about the android apps. Can you explain the flow between the android apps and web service more specific. I think the flow between them: First the android apps login, then the web service create cookies or session and the android apps can use other method in the web service. Is that right?